# Missing row 'I' in package numbering convention: why?

Tags: pcb, packages

So, I recently discovered a quite painful mistake in my PCB regarding the PGA socket numbering. I have used a row numbered `I` in my footprint, while the package has no such row. The numbering of the package rows goes alphabetically, from A till H, skips I, and then continues on with `J`. I was not aware of this. Consequently, the actual row `J` on the package has no connection, row `K` is connected to the pins of row `J` instead, and so on ...

When looking up if I had just stumbled across an exotic PGA package, or if this really was a convention, I found evidence that it probably is the latter. Here are a few datasheets where every time the row `I` is missing:

- https://www.spectrum-semi.com/CPG08451.pdf
- https://www.arieselec.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/13x13-footprints.pdf
- https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.pdf

This leads me to 2 questions:

1. Is it indeed an industry standard to skip row `I`?
2. Why is this done? I immediately thought of confusion between the number `1` and the letter `I`. Or confusion between capital `I` and lowercase `l` ? But the first does not make sense because you know the first symbol must be a letter, and the latter is easily avoided if you always use capital letters... (or if you consequently use lowercase).

Comment: Don't assume that the uppercase I, lowercase l, and digit 1 have a significantly different appearance in **all possible fonts**.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Absolutely! I am also not saying that. I mean that you can easily deduce from context if the first symbol in the pin designator represents a number, a lower case letter, or an upper case letter. Once you know that, there is no confusion possible anymore.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  The US military seems to prefer sans-serif fonts. Eg. MIL-STD-130. The differences are less distinct without serifs.

Answer (score 4):

This is also standard in military-style connectors, no doubt for the reason you state (to prevent confusion between '1' and 'I' as well as '0' and 'O'). 'Q' is also skipped. Image from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381418/pin-letters-not-shown-in-circular-connectors-d38999-series) answer but ultimately from MIL-STD-1560.

[image]

Comment: That's even more remarkable! With what would one confuse the letter O in this case? There is no number (no zero) at all in the numbering of the contacts in that  connector...

Comment: If you never use I, O, Q you never have to worry about whether there are numbers involved or not.